# charindex in case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, charindex

I am fairly new to SQL Server and was given the below case statement and I am having a hard time understanding what its doing.

I think its taking the 835 column checking to see if the claim value is (greater then 1) and if so then to relook at that column and bring in the Claim ID. And that is as far as I get in my thinking. Can some explain to me what it is doing?

```
case
    when charindex(' ', ltrim(rtrim(ani.edi835claimicn))) > 1 then
        substring(ltrim(rtrim(ani.edi835claimicn)), 1, charindex(' ', ltrim(rtrim(ani.edi835claimicn))) - 1)
    else
        ltrim(rtrim(ani.edi835claimicn))
end as icn
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanatio nof what you want to do would really help.

Comment: You could easily get some insight by just taking this expression and feeding it some values in a separate `SELECT` by substituting for `ani.edi835claimicn`. Specifically values that contain a space somewhere in the middle, and values that don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply extracts the substring before first space character in the input string (the value inside column `ani.edi835claimicn`). If the string does not contain space then the input string is used as-is.

Comment: Thank you so much . This make sense to me.